# Redirection operator vs file handling

Tags: file, unix, input, posix, stdin

When writing a simple program for a POSIX-compliant OS which accepts input and produces output, when and why should

```
myprogram file.in
```

be preffered over

```
myprogram < file.in
```

and vice versa?

I like the latter because I feel that file handling should be the responsibility of the shell, not my program. On the other hand, I'm not so sure how the same code could work for both files and stdin—shouldn't stdin be interactive, i.e. prompt you for your input? Whereas in a file, the format is understood and predefined, e.g. there is a single integer which is the input value (in which case *another* option would be to simply accept the value as a command line argument), or each line contains a test case which is a list of space-separated numbers, etc.

Examples would be great.

*Note that I've already seen [Shell redirection vs explicit file handling code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184165/shell-redirection-vs-explicit-file-handling-code) and none of the answers really answered this question in a general sense.*

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to expect stdin to be interactive.  Making that assumption gets many people into trouble and causes a lot of software to be far less useful than it ought to be.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: So would you say go with redirection for files, and treat stdin as if it was a file (no interactive prompts)? I'm just thinking, if the program accepts two numbers and then does something, nothing happens until you press enter twice, whereas with a file, which is all already there, you can display an error message if the file isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: @Mk12 : your program can actually tell the difference between being interactive and reading redirected `stdin`. Check the program `bc` - type `bc` at the command line and it is interactive. Type `3 + 7` hit enter and it says `10`. `Ctrl+D` to exit. Now create a file with 1 line saying `3 + 7` and run `bc < myfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is down to preference, and the intended use of your program should inform your decision.

The [UNIX philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) suggests writing simple tools connected by clean interfaces. Creating a tool that accepts stdin will make it more versatile. You will be able to feed the tool from existing files, or from the output of any other POSIX command.

Answer (score 1):

Most POSIX utilities will act on a file if one is given at the command line, or on stdin/stdout if no file(s) specified. Common styles are

- `myprogram filename`
- `myprogram -f filename`
- `myprogram --file=filename`

Or individual input and output specifiable.

This allows the flexibility of supplying a file, or using redirection or pipelining.

`main` handles parameters and opening a file if necessary, then passes off the open file stream -- whether it's from `stdin` or the file you opened -- to your processing function.

This fits in with the UNIX philosophy, as sgmorrison mentioned.